# Xenu link checker can't see the url links in html code

Tags: php, html, url, xenu

I need to check with Xenu application a view links on my www site.

On my site there is HTML code.

```
<img src="mysite/pictures.php?url=http://othersite.com/pic1.jpg">
<img src="mysite/pictures.php?url=http://othersite.com/pic2.jpg">
<img src="mysite/pictures.php?url=http://othersite.com/pic3.jpg">
```

But Xenu cannot check if pictures exist or not. How I can do it with some script inside `pictures.php`?

I need to check for example if the link in parameter `url=http://othersite.com/pic1.jpg` is a JPG picture.
I can't change the HTML code because it must be constant. So I have to do it with some PHP script.

Comment: Maybe something in javascript? In html code I've got <class="proxed" img src=.... yet.There must be solution for that.

Answer (score 0):

You have many ways to do this the best as I always use is [Simple HTML DOM](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm) :-

```
<?php 
    include(simple_html_dom);
    $html=new simplehtmldom();
    $html->file_get_html('http://exampl.com');
     foreach($html->find(img)->src as $scr) {
     echo=strplace('mysite/pictures.php?url=','',$scr);
      }
    ?>
```